# Javascript read a file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I was hoping that maybe someone can help me out:

I created a bash script that connects to my free webhost via FTP and uploads a file.txt
into the home directory. What I'm looking to do is to read this text and display it on my index.html site.

Looking around I seen the following script:

```
jQuery.get('path/to/file/on/server.txt', null, function(data, status) {
    // your file contents are in 'data'
});
```

how would I output 'data'?

Or is there any other method someone can recommend?

thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
$.get("file.txt", function(data){
  alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
});
```

Edit: taken from the [jQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.get)

Answer (score 1):

Get the contents of file.txt and display inside a div with id "id":

```
$.get("file.txt", function(data){
   $("#id").text(data);
});
```